# c++ quaternion clarification

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm working on a flight simulator. I've read a tutorial about quaternions, ( this one : http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-17-quaternions/ ), so It it very new for me.

From what I've understand, quaternions should rotate an object using a direction vector and make the object's orientation match the direction, and rotate the quaternion should not move the vector, but just make him turn around himself. Am I true?

If yes, this is my code :

```
void Plane::Update()
{
    m_matrix = GLM_GTX_quaternion::toMat4( GLM_GTX_quaternion::angleAxis( radians( m_angle ), normalize( m_planeDirection ) ) );
}
```

When my plane model's is pointing to x vector, my plane will rotate correctly around the x vector with the angle equal to 0, but if I change the angle, it will not rotate correctly. So how can I find the angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct - *Quaternion rotates an object around a directional vector*. You should also use the **glm::quat** typedef when working with quaternions.

```
#include <glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp>
//...
glm::mat4 m = glm::mat4_cast(glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(m_angle), glm::normalize(m_planeDirection)));
```

**glm::rotate** function also works with quaternions

```
glm::mat4 m = glm::mat4_cast(glm::rotate(glm::quat(), 45.0f, glm::vec3(1.0f)));
```

Comment: But then, why does angleAxis( 0.0f, vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f ) ) orientate my plane to the x vector?

Comment: To the x axis* I mean.

Comment: I guess I'm having a hard time understanding what your problem is. But you did say here _"quaternions should rotate an object using a direction vector and make the object's orientation **match the direction**"_. So you might be looking for a LookAt function (which makes sense since you're using to planes), it's discussed in the article you've linked.

Comment: After understanding the things I was trying to understand, my question seems very confusing. In fact, I misunderstood the angle-axis rotation, same as this question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430311/problems-converting-axis-angle-to-quaternion ) and was trying to make my plane orientation with that... and that's not the right tool for that. Thanks for pointing me out lookAt function, and the sections in the tutorial, I didn't even saw them...